# Insert huddle to a key

Tags: tcl

Desired output :

```
{"series": [
    {
      "Name": "serie1",
      "data": [
        12,
        99,
        35
      ]
    },
    {
      "Name": "serie2",
      "data": [
        12,
        50,
        35
      ]
    }
  ]}
```

I have 3 huddles like this :

```
set serieskey {HUDDLE {D {series {L {}}}}}
set serie1 {HUDDLE {D {Name {s serie1} data {L {{num 12} {num 99} {num 35}}}}}}
set serie2 {HUDDLE {D {Name {s serie2} data {L {{num 12} {num 50} {num 35}}}}}}
```

huddle [combine](https://core.tcl-lang.org/tcllib/doc/tcllib-1-18/embedded/www/tcllib/files/modules/yaml/huddle.html#13) $serieskey $serie1

```
HUDDLE {D {series {L {}} Name {s serie1} data {L {{num 12} {num 99} {num 35}}}}}
> {
  "series": [
    
  ],
  "Name": "serie1",
  "data": [
    12,
    99,
    35
  ]
}
```

adds out of my `series`

maybe huddle [append](https://core.tcl-lang.org/tcllib/doc/tcllib-1-18/embedded/www/tcllib/files/modules/yaml/huddle.html#15) would do the job but I don’t know how to use it knowing that my main key already exists...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I finally found with [set](https://core.tcl-lang.org/tcllib/doc/tcllib-1-18/embedded/www/tcllib/files/modules/yaml/huddle.html#11) command:

```
huddle set serieskey series 0 $serie1
huddle set serieskey series 1 $serie2
```

Hope that it might help others...